# When accessing a Vaadin app behind a Zuul proxy get a Cookies disabled error

Tags: vaadin, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, vaadin8

Trying to access a Vaadin application built on top of Spring Cloud.  The application returns an error stating Cookies Disabled click here or hit ESC.

Cookies are enabled within the browser.

Configuration is Vaadin app registers with Eureka and Zuul proxies all request.

```
vaadin-app:
  path: /ui/vaadin/**
  stripPrefix: false
```

The Vaadin app does not use Spring Security or Vaadin Security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix ended up being fairly simple.  Added `sensitiveHeaders: Authorization`

Now with this configuration within Zuul, the Vaadin application loads normally.  Once more no security is being used.  Probably would be required if security was enabled.

```
vaadin-app:
  path: /ui/vaadin/**
  stripPrefix: false
  sensitiveHeaders: Authorization
```

Comment: Docs FYI http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#_cookies_and_sensitive_headers